# Why does the py-script fall into def_shutdown() in threading.py?

Tags: python

I run a script on Ubuntu 18. It takes frames from a video camera, forms a thread, outputs stream elements in a queue, and performs further processing.

```py
def get_img(queue_img):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_file_or_camera)

    while True:
        ret = cap.grab()
        _, img = cap.retrieve()

        if queue_img.qsize() == 2:
            queue_img.get()
        queue_img.put(img)

class Video(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        queue_img = queue.Queue(maxsize=2)
        threading_read_img = threading.Thread(target=get_img, args(queue_img,))
        threading_read_img.start()
        ...
```

`pdb.set_trace()` showed, after grabbing and processing the first frame, the thread gets up, goes to the `def_shutdown()` (in the threading.py script) and waits for the end of something.

```
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1355)_shutdown()
-> def _shutdown():
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1364)_shutdown()
-> if _main_thread._is_stopped:
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1369)_shutdown()
-> tlock = _main_thread._tstate_lock
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1372)_shutdown()
-> assert tlock is not None
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1373)_shutdown()
-> assert tlock.locked()
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1374)_shutdown()
-> tlock.release()
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1375)_shutdown()
-> _main_thread._stop()
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1379)_shutdown()
-> with _shutdown_locks_lock:
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1380)_shutdown()
-> locks = list(_shutdown_locks)
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1381)_shutdown()
-> _shutdown_locks.clear()
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1383)_shutdown()
-> if not locks:
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1386)_shutdown()
-> for lock in locks:
> /usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py(1388)_shutdown()
-> lock.acquire()
```

Then the script does not work, and it does not give an error. At this time, frames from the video camera are cut for streaming.
The script works on another PC with Ubuntu 18 PC. What PC settings might conflict with Thread?

Comment: Please provide the full script.